# HTTP Post method not supported by this URL when deployed to jboss EAP 7.1

Tags: java, spring-boot, jboss7.x, restful-url

I've a REST API, that is deployed on JBoss EAP 7.1. When I hit the URL at

```
http://localhost:8080/MyApp/group
```

in postman, it gives "HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL" error with status code 405.

When I deploy this API on embedded tomcat server, it works perfectly fine. Here is my controller

```
@RestController
public class RequestController {
    
    @Autowired
    private GroupService groupService;
    
    @PostMapping( "/group" )
    public GroupInfo fetchGroupInfo( @RequestBody GroupInfo groupInfo ) {
        
        long groupId = groupInfo.getGroupId();
        return groupService.getGroup( groupId );
        
    }

}
```

main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder){
        return builder.sources(MyApp.class);
    }
    
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.my.package</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>MyApp</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <finalName>MyApp</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The deployment shows no error messages. However, it does show below warning

```
 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYWELD0013: Deployment optumRx-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war contains CDI annotations but no bean archive was found (no beans.xml or class with bean defining annotations was present).
```

And the class files are missing in the deployment folder in jboss. Can you please tell, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I missed the servlet api dependency in my project. After I add that dependency everything is working fine. The embedded Tomcat server have this jar and so, it was not needed when I deployed on Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

About path: construction in pom.xml < finalName> MyApp < / finalName> doesn't says about way in url, it's about name of artifact.
Try to use http://localhost:8080/group (without MyApp)

About other: if you want deploy on jboss, you must exclude tomcat in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions> 
</dependency>
```

About CDI warning - try to use @ComponentScan(basePackages="your.package") on MyApp class

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Yes, you are correct. I made this change too in addition to that I missed servlet API dependency in my pom.